# JUnit Parameterized Tests - IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, parameters

I'm developing a Java Spring project. I have little experience with JUnit, and encountered this problem when creating parameterized tests.

I'm making a sample test of the method ReportTableOperations.addDurations() which is basically  a SUM of two long values.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ReportTableOperationsTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
      return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
          {3600L, 3600L, 7200L},
          {2000L, 3600L, 5600L}
      });
    }

    private long value1, value2, expected;

    public void AddDurationsTest(long value1, long value2, long expected) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
        this.expected = expected;
    }


    @Test
    public void testAddDurations() throws Exception {

        assertThat(ReportTableOperations.addDurations(value1, value2), is(expected));

    } 

 }
```

But I'm encountering the following errors when executing the test:

```
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments**

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.createTestUsingConstructorInjection(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.java:38)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

Anyone has any ideas in what could be causing this?

Comment: Is there a typo somewhere? Parameterized test needs constructor or field injection. Your thing looks kinda like it wants to do constructor injection, but there is no constructor, there is a method called `AddDurationsTest`.

Comment: Ha, I was looking in the wrong spot for this Exception and your question made it obvious where the error was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor name should be the same as class name and shouldn't declare returning type. You have class `ReportTableOperationsTest` and method which pretend to be constructor `void AddDurationsTest` . So just fix it like

```
private long value1, value2, expected;

public ReportTableOperationsTest(long value1, long value2, long expected) {
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
    this.expected = expected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an example of how to implement this in Kotlin for those Kotlin coders who come across here. The example is from here: https://gist.github.com/rossharper/8f6c3c169b6b5c23e12c

```
@RunWith(Parameterized::class)
class KotlinTest(val paramOne: Int, val paramTwo: String) {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Parameterized.Parameters
        fun data() : Collection<Array<Any>> {
            return listOf(
                    arrayOf(1, "I"),         // First test:  (paramOne = 1, paramTwo = "I")
                    arrayOf(1999, "MCMXCIX") // Second test: (paramOne = 1999, paramTwo = "MCMXCIX")
            )
        }
    }
```